# Cannot access class and methods from custom jars in Maven

Tags: maven, jar, dependency-management

I have created a project in java and compiled it as a jar with the `mvn clean install` command. The jar is in my local `.m2` folder. I am trying to import it as a dependency in a new project. The jar is successfully imported into my new project but I cannot access any classes or methods in that jar.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>rest-methods</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

This my custom maven dependency imported in my External Libraries

[image]

And this is when I try to use these class and any method inside it in my project:

[image]

When I try to add the maven dependency manually I can find it and I can click add but nothing happens

[image]

Am I missing some steps for using this class in my project? I am working on a `Ubuntu 20.04` operating system

**UPDATE**: After looking in the Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Libraries I see that several files from the jar are marked as excluded (sources and JavaDocs):

[image]

Did they not get build properly when I created the jar ?

Comment: Does your dependency `rest-methods` use a spring boot parent?

Comment: No. It is a simple Maven project. Both the dependency and the project I am trying to import it in.

Comment: What happens when you run `clean install` on the importing project?

Comment: When I run ``mvn clean install`` it is executed successfully. I can see the jar and the contents of the jar are imported in the External Libraries. I just can use them in my project.

Comment: So, running `mvn clean install` on your new project works as well?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. I just don't understand why it does not see my class.

Comment: So, this is just a problem that your IDE is not showing the dependency correctly? You probably need to refresh the content or restart the IDE.

Comment: I tried to refresh the IDE - I am using IntelliJ - but it does not work. Could it be related to the scope ( ``<scope>compile</scope>`` ) for the dependency?

Comment: The scope is right. If it compiles, it is the fault of IntelliJ, not Maven.

Comment: I just posted an update in the main description from the Project Structure